# Tensorflow TPU Issue Kaggle

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, kaggle, tpu

I am working on a notebook in Kaggle and trying to connect to the TPU. When I check if I have connected to TPU with this code:

```
AUTO = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

# Detect TPU, return appropriate distribution strategy
try:
    tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver()
    print('Running on TPU ', tpu.master())
except ValueError:
    tpu = None

if tpu:
    tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(tpu)
    tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(tpu)
    strategy = tf.distribute.TPUStrategy(tpu)
else:
    strategy = tf.distribute.get_strategy()

print("REPLICAS: ", strategy.num_replicas_in_sync)
```

I get output this:

```
REPLICAS: 1
```

I do not know why I am getting this.., when I would have to get a total of 8 replics.

How can I fix it? My version of tensorflow is 2.2.0. I tried with the last version but I get the same output.

Also, I have this information that I do not know why:

[image]

Why there is a '?' in TPU ?

Thanks. Wish your answers.